# Excel PivotTable: Multiple Rows from Multiple Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I had the following data in Excel:

```
Points | Categories
---------------------------
25     | Cat1, Cat2, Cat3
15     | Cat2, Cat3
19     | Cat1
20     | Cat1, Cat3
```

But since I couldn't really show this in a pivot chart how I wanted, I converted it to:

```
Points | Cat1  | Cat2  | Cat3
------------------------------
25     | TRUE  | TRUE  | TRUE
15     | FALSE | TRUE  | TRUE 
19     | TRUE  | FALSE | FALSE
20     | TRUE  | FALSE | TRUE
```

.. and I also tried

```
Points | Cat1  | Cat2  | Cat3
------------------------------
25     | Cat1  | Cat2  | Cat3
15     |       | Cat2  | Cat3 
19     | Cat1  |       | 
20     | Cat1  |       | Cat3
```

... but I keep getting a pivot table that looks like:

```
Row Labels | Average of Points
------------------------------
Cat1       |
   Cat2    |
      Cat3 |          <some #>
```

... when I actually want

```
Row Labels | Average of Points
------------------------------
Cat1       |          <some #>
Cat2       |          <some #>
Cat3       |          <some #>
```

How can I do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need your data in this format

```
Points  Cat
25      Cat1
25      Cat2
25      Cat3
15      Cat2
15      Cat3
19      Cat1
19      Cat1
20      Cat3
```

Comment: Dr Moxie's rules for Pivot Tables: 

1: Build your data downwards – utilise the rows and not the columns

2: All values of the same type should be reported in one column – with a single field heading. 

Obey those, and it's hard to make a Pivot Table incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Under Pivot Table Tools, Design, Report layout, select **Show In Tabular Form**

[image: Show In Tabular Form]

Comment: Then it looks like this: https://gyazo.com/a60c135b55e0726b2b8fa3517b6b38a3.

The point of getting the PivotTable like that is so that I can have a PivotChart with bar graph, where each bar shows the average points for each category.

Answer (score 0):

This article answers your question.

[A super easy way to generate new records from multi-value columns using Excel Power Query](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/a-super-easy-way-to-generate-new-records-from-multi-value-columns-using-excels-power-query/)

**Key points from the link:**

First load the data in power query, then create the new rows using delimiter query.

Click anywhere inside the Table.Click the Data tab.In the Get & Transform Data group, click From Table/Range. (If the data isn’t a Table, Excel will run you through the steps necessary to convert the data into one.)Excel will launch the Query Editor. Each column header identifies its data type for easy visual confirmation.
Select the Items row (click the header cell).Click the Split Column option in the Transform group, and choose By Delimiter from the resulting dropdown list.The resulting dialog prompts you to identify the delimiter. Retain the default option, Each occurrence of the delimiter, but don’t click OK yet.Click Advance options.In the Split into section, select Rows and click OK.

You now have the data to work with.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1154773)